# Error with Jdom 2.0.5 and java during my compilation

Tags: java, linux, classpath, linux-mint, jdom-2

I try to compil with jdom, my directory look like that :

jdom-2.0.5.jar, ParseurXml.java, XMLEnt.xml

i've already try to export my classpath, but It still not woking at all.

My ParseurXML.java contain only tree import, and write that in my stderr :

> ParseurXml.java:2: error: package org.jdom does not exist import
>   org.jdom.*; ^ ParseurXml.java:3: error: package org.jdom.input does
>   not exist import org.jdom.input.*; ^ ParseurXml.java:4: error: package
>   org.jdom.output does not exist import org.jdom.output.*; ^
>   ParseurXml.java:12: error: package org.jdom does not exist    static
>   org.jdom.Document document;

I compile like that: 
javac -classpath jdom-2.0.5.jar ParseurXml.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you're in the same directory as these files when calling javac, its' nearly always a good idea to include the current directory in the classpath

On linux you can use this

```
javac -classpath .:./jdom-2.0.5.jar ParseurXml.java
```

So the above specifies the current directory at the start of the classpath (i.e. the leading `.` character)

Then the following `:` character is a separator

Then the following `./jdom-2.0.5.jar` says to look for your jdom jar file in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

JDOM 2.0.5 is in the package `org.jdom2.*` and not in the package `org.jdom.*`.

You must have some code that is using the older JDOM 1.x version.

Have a look at this page where which gives details on how to [migrate from one to the other](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-Migration-Issues). I don't know why you have code-dependencies of JDOM 1.x classes if you are sure you are using JDOM2, but the migration path should be easy.